# How do I disable hiding of the mouse pointer while typing text?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse

I think I'm finally annoyed enough with my mouse pointer disappearing as I start typing to want to do something about it.

I want to move the mouse. I want to click. I want to start typing, but I want the mouse pointer to stay as is. I end up having to move the mouse just to figure out where the pointer is and I hate that.

How do I do this? Is this a switch I can toggle from within Mac OS or will I have to use a third-party app? I dug around System Preferences and Keyboard settings, but I didn't find anything relevant.

I'm running Mountain Lion 10.8.2 on an iMac. At this moment, it's a Microsoft Wireless Mobile Mouse 1000 along with the regular Apple Wireless Keyboard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the default global behavior and can't be changed through a system preference. (I can't find any third-party utilities to change this either.)

Apple's reasoning is probably that users (but not all users) don't want the mouse pointer to obscure the text while typing. A developer might work around this by using `NSCursor` with `setHiddenUntilMouseMoves:NO` or `unhide`, etc., but this would be considered bad form due to creating an inconsistent user experience compared to other apps.

Comment: Yes, I know the reasoning behind it, but I just want to know if I can change it. The answer, as you say, is no.

Answer (score -1):

[Mouse Locator](http://www.2point5fish.com/index.html) is a (32-bit) preference pane that will allow you to set a keyboard shortcut to show where the mouse is. You can also set a trigger time in addition or in lieu of a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I don't want to locate the mouse. I want to prevent it from hiding in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

There are several programs that will highlight where the mouse is on a given key press;  apart from [Mouse Locator](http://www.2point5fish.com/index.html) mathioned above there is [OmniDazzle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnidazzle/) or [Mouseposé](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mousepose/id405904955?mt=12)